Accessing hardware UART via unity game built for android
I would like to access the hardware serial port (tty*) , not the usb serial port(last resort if not possible), via unity, I have no experience in android development and have barely managed to get a running game in unity.
My game should send and receive data to/from hardware serial port provided by the manufacturer(I can see the connectors provided for usage by software).For hardware protion, assume I have it ready on my end.
I tried building a java warpper,including some .jar file to plugins folder and also edited the manifest and gradle file in unity and some stuff suggested by chatGPT , to the extent I tried android studio to build custom library(jar/aar) for integration with unity, but with no prior knowledge in this domain, I am stuck.
I do not wish(and also don't know)to use the usb for serial plugin as it uses a usb-uart adapter, whereas I have two serial ports exposed on android hardware for usage, and one on my hardware.
Please help/guide,provide resource,I am also open to your help in building that uart bridge sort of for my game, any pointers would be greatly be appreciated.
